# WOT closure and SOT closure of convex sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading some papers on operators acting on Banach spaces and one of them uses the following fact:

> If a vector space has two locally convex topologies with identical collections of continuos linear functionals, then a convex set has the same closure in both topologies.

I wonder where I can find a proof for this fact. 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to combine three result from chapter 3 of Rudin's Functional Analysis Book.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be some locally convex topological vector space. Let $(X,\tau)'$ be the space of linear functionals on $X$ that continuous in $\tau$ topology. Since $\tau$ is a locally convex topology, then $X'$ separates points in $X$ (corollary of theorem 3.4).

Let $\tau'$ be topology on $X$ induced by functionals from $X'$, then by theorem 3.10 the space $(X,\tau')$ is a locally convex and surprisingly $(X,\tau')'=(X,\tau)'$.

So, in order to prove the result you mentioned in your question it is enough to consider case when one of the topologies is a weak topology.

Now we apply theorem 3.12. It states, that each convex subset $E$ of locally convex space $X$ have equal closures in original and weak topologies.

And now we are done.

Comment: Can you elaborate why assuming weak topology handles the remaining case. Sorry for commenting on an ancient post.

Comment: By assumption of original question the topologies being compared both have the same set of continuous functionals. As you might know, weak topology is generated by continuous functionals and this topology is weaker than the original one.