# Bounded operators: $\langle T_n (x),x \rangle \longrightarrow 0 \implies T_n (x) \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $(T_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and that for every $x \in \mathcal{H}$
$$
\langle T_n (x),x \rangle \longrightarrow 0 \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$$

Is it then true that $T_n (x) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $x \in \mathcal{H}$?

---

I am not sure whether or not this is true. One the one hand it could be that $T_n (x)$ converges to something in the orthogonal complement of a subsapce containing $x$ but also this seems odd if this holds for any $x \in \mathcal{H}$. We know that the inner-product is continuous in the first entry but I can't see that this is useful here to show the claim.

Any help towards a proof, counter-example or reference is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you encountered the polar identity? This will show you that the condition $\langle T_nx, x\rangle\to 0$ for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$ is equivalent to $T_n\to 0$ in the *weak* operator topology. Also, if $T_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$ then $T_n$ converges to zero in the *strong* operator topology. Do you know when these topologies coincide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *polar identity* states
$$
\langle Tx, y\rangle = \frac14\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \langle T(x + i^ky), x + i^ky\rangle
$$
This is a well-known identity, which can be derived from two simpler observations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle Tx, y\rangle + \langle Ty, x\rangle & = \frac12\left(\langle T(x + y), x + y\rangle - \langle T(x - y), x - y\rangle\right) \\
\langle Tx, y\rangle - \langle Ty, x\rangle & = \frac1{2i}\left(\langle T(x - iy), x - iy\rangle - \langle T(x + iy), x + iy\rangle\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, if $\langle T_n x, x\rangle\to 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$, then $\langle T_n x, y\rangle$, being a sum of four terms of the form $\langle T_n z, z\rangle$ for some $z\in\mathcal{H}$, also tends to zero. So $T_n$ converges to zero in the *weak operator topology* (or WOT).

On the other hand, $T_nx\to 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$ is just saying $T_n\to 0$ in the *strong operator topology* (or SOT).

In general, these topologies are not equivalent; the SOT is *strictly finer* than the WOT, which is to say that there are more SOT-open sets than WOT-open sets, or equivalently every SOT-convergent net of operators is WOT-convergent (via the Cauchy-Schwarz identity).

Consider the right-shift operator $R \in\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)$ taking $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ to $(0, a_1, a_2, ...)$. It's not too hard to check that $R^n$ converges weakly to zero, but each $R^n$ is an isometry, and so cannot converge strongly to zero.

---

Clarifying the discussion in the comments, I had mistakenly claimed that the WOT and SOT coincide for certain types of sets. This isn't true, and it's an easy trap to fall into (I've made this mistake before)!

What is true:

1. If $U\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is bounded, then the *strong* and *ultra-strong* (resp. *weak* and *ultra-weak*) topologies on $U$ are **identical**: they have the same open sets.
2. If $C\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is convex, then $\overline{C}^{WOT} = \overline{C}^{SOT}$. This is because the WOT and SOT topologies have precisely the same continuous linear functionals (in fact, any two locally convex topologies on a vector space with the same continuous linear functionals enjoy this property: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/147098/111920)).

This second fact does *not* mean that the WOT-open and SOT-open subsets of $C$ are the same.

Comment: @Zerox Yes, but only under the assumption that $T_n$ is uniformly bounded. Otherwise there are counterexamples.

Comment: I'm curious about the counter-examples, would you include that in your answer?

Comment: @Zerox Yeah I'll see if I can find a good example. I'd be surprised if there weren't already examples on this site, all we need is an unbounded net of operators which converges weakly to zero but not strongly to zero.

Comment: @Zerox Give me a sec, I misquoted something. It's not the strong and weak topologies which coincide on bounded sets (though I think they coincide on *convex* sets), rather it's the strong and ultrastrong (or weak and ultraweak) topologies which coincide. There is an instance when the strong and weak topologies coincide, but I need to check.

Comment: Well, the left-shift operators are indeed counter-examples for the seperable case. What is interesting would then happen in the inseperable case.

Comment: @Zerox What's confusing me is that the left-shift operators are isometries, and so live inside the unit ball of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, a bounded convex set, and so would converge strongly to zero as well (since the WOT and SOT supposedly coincide in this environment). I'm not sure what's going awry just yet.

Comment: They indeed converge **weakly** to $0$. A counter-example just need they not converge **strongly** to $0$.

Comment: @Zerox Ah I've found my error. So, the strong and ultrastrong (resp. weak and ultraweak) topologies do indeed *coincide* on bounded sets. But the weak and strong _topologies_ don't coincide on a convex set. Rather, the weak and strong _closures_ of a convex set coincide.

Answer (score 1):

For seperable **real** Hilbert spaces there is a counter-example: Let $T_n \equiv T$ such that $Te_{2i}=e_{2i+1} ,Te_{2i+1}=-e_{2i}$ for $i \ge 0$, where $\{ e_i \}_{i \ge 0}$ is an orthonormal base. Then clearly $T_n(x) \equiv T(x) \ne 0$ but $\langle T_n(x),x \rangle \equiv \langle T(x),x \rangle = 0$.
For inseperable **real** Hilbert spaces similar construction can be made if there is a convolution with no fixed point on the orthonormal base, but I'm afraid some set-theoretic methods will be involved.

*Another Construction*: Choose a two-dimensional subspace $V$ of the ambient Hilbert space. Suppose $a,b$ is an orthonormal base of $V$. Define the bounded linear map $T$ to be $Ta=b,Tb=-a,T|_{V^{\perp}}=0$ and take $T_n \equiv T$. This works for every **real** Hilbert space.

For the complex case, as @user3002473 pointed out, a counter-example can be taken to be a WOT-null operator sequence that is not SOT-null. So in the seperable case a counter-example is $T_n=R^n$, where $Re_i=e_{i+1}$ is the right-shift operator. (This apparently also works for the real case.)

Comment: Couldn't we pick two orthonormal vectors, define the action as you did on this subspace and extend the operator by zero on the orthogonal complement of our $2$-dimensional space? This would then work for all real Hilbert spaces without invoking much set theory.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven This is also an example, but I prefer isomorphisms.

Comment: That is of course a valid opinion. I tend to prefer low-tech counterexample.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Fine. I'll include yours.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mean it this way. Math is very much a matter of preferences. Your construction is a bit heavier, but also gives a stronger result.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ahh I'm not offended. Your method is cool and adapts to wider situations. But sadly both of our methods don't work for the complex case.